# I would like to ask how to apply a trigger in C# wpf project on 3D object?

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

[Image of the main window with the 3D objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bno67.png)

I have imported two 3D models as you can see in the image from the link above in to my WPF project and i would like to ask how i could add trigger that would open another window from this main window based on a mouse clicking on one of those 3D objects that would have a trigger applied to it

Answer (score 1):

What type is the 3D Model ? If you are using a ModelUIElement3D, you can attach a mousedown event to both of the models like such.

```
model1.MouseDown += (sender,e) => CreateNewWindow("First");
model2.MouseDown += (sender,e) => CreateNewWindow("Second");
```

Then you can open a new window according to the parameter sent using this CreateNewWindow(string windowToOpen) function